# Is there a way to view known blueprints without an empty upgrade slot?

Tags: no-mans-sky

Consider the Multi-tool. I randomly encountered an Alien who gave me a very good multi-tool with very strong lasers and stuff. All I had to add was the scanner and I was good to go.

However, after a while, I began wondering if it was worth deconstructing some of the upgrades in case I know a higher-tier blueprint. But I am not certain about which blueprints I know. As far as I'm aware, the only way to view the list of my known multi-tool blueprints is to deconstruct one slot and try to craft something new in it. But this seems wasteful. Is there not a way to view the list of known blueprints otherwise?

Comment: In your specific case, it shouldn't be resource intensive at all to quickly dismantle the Analyser, check what you can build, then re-assemble it.

Comment: True, but this is something they could easily implement into the game tbh. Weird it wasn't a feature from the start..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not for the multi-tool (on PS4).

All products that can be constructed in the suit can also be constructed in the ship, so if you have no free slot in one you can at least check product blueprints in the other.  (Not so for upgrades, of course.)

On the plus (?) side, enhancement blueprints [seem to be pretty limited](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/281719/50264) (at least as far as I am into the game) so if you get only duplicate suit, ship, and multi-tool blueprints 100 times in row, it's a good bet you've found everything.

Of course that still doesn't help if you're just trying to check the ingredient list for an upgrade, which is where the internets come in. :)

Comment: Thought so. Ahh, that's too bad.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the guide screen (between options and log) and select Technology.... if I'm remembering correctly, the blueprints you have will have a wrench icon in the lower right corner

Answer (score 0):

The suit, multitool and the ship have a max number of blue prints to achieve. Only the multitool is incapable of hold all the available tech. The reason for this is that the multitool max is at 24 slots, some of the items are not conducive with other components. Mostly, it's the rebounding grenades. Either you want them to bounce or not. Should you install both, bounce becomes the default making the other void, and waste a slot. Bouncing them only allows them to be thrown further, and then you better have the timing and distance down.

The ship tech max is at 30. So unless you're hanging onto the atlas stones (10), you will have 18 slots available for trading or extra materials to fix things when they break post haste, which if you go through a black hole, happens often.

If you bought a ship or multitool with upgraded tech already installed and for whatever reason (voluntary dismantle, pirate attack, black hole), you cannot craft a new one without a blueprint and they're not for sale, one has to play the game and finding them is a grind. On a good note, once you have them, they're yours to keep.